# Access Meta StackOverflow from Android app

Tags: support, meta, android-app, stack-exchange

I have installed Stack Exchange Android app.
I can access all SE sites. But not able to see Meta sites.
How to access meta SO from Android app?

Comment: I had to search around for a bit too when I first got the app. It's a bit hidden. It would be nice if there were a button somewhere to go to Meta for the site that you are looking at...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The meta sites are in a different category. Under "all sites", there's a box in the top right corner labeled "main sites". Click on it and select "meta sites" or "all sites", and then search for the site you're looking for.

[image] [image] [image]